# Store filenames in array VC++

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

I am trying to get all the filenames into an array . But after reading all the filenames the array only have the last filename;

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>


int main() {

    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd; 
    HANDLE handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    TCHAR *directory = L"D:/*.*";
    LPCWSTR filenames[30] ;
    handle = FindFirstFile(directory, &ffd);
    int count = 0; 
    if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        OutputDebugString(ffd.cFileName);
        do {
            filenames[count++] = ffd.cFileName;

            OutputDebugString(filenames[count -1]);
        } while (FindNextFile(handle, &ffd) != 0);

    }
    else {
        OutputDebugString(L"Nothing to display \n"); 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        OutputDebugString(filenames[i]);
    }
    FindClose(handle);
    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

What is the problem I have in this code .. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LPCWSTR filenames[30];
```

Above is a character array. It is not an array of strings. It is also too short to contain a filename which can be `MAX_PATH` long.

Use `wchar_t **buf;` to create an array of strings, or use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

If file handle is invalid then do not close it.

Don't use `TCHAR` unless it is part of some homework or something. Just use `wchar_t` for Windows.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> vec;

    wchar_t *directory = L"D:/*.*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(directory, &ffd);
    if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        do {
            vec.push_back(ffd.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(handle, &ffd));
        FindClose(handle);
    }
    else 
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Nothing to display \n");
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        OutputDebugString(vec[i].c_str());
        OutputDebugString(L"\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```